# Pandas Groupby Lambda function multiple conditions/columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by

I am trying to create a new column that groups df by `Deal` and `Month`, and applies a percentage (9%) to the `Amount` column. If all the `Amount` values for a particular `Deal` in a particular month add up to 20,000 then apply the percentage to the `Amount`; otherwise, if the `TYPE` is `MONTHLY`, and the individual `Amount` is at least 1500, apply the percentage to the `Amount`; failing that, multiply by 0.

```
df.groupby(['Deal', 'Month'])["Amount"].apply(
    lambda x: x.sum() * 0.09 if x.sum() >= 20000 else (
        x * 0.09 if x >= 1500 and x['TYPE'] == 'MONTHLY' else 0
    )
)
```

This is what I tried but keep getting errors such as `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` OR `KeyError: ('TYPE', u'occurred at index 0')` etc. I've tried using transform instead of apply too. Would greatly appreciate any help.

This if what my grouped DF looks like + Desired Column

```
   Deal         TYPE    Month        Amount   Desired Column
0   Com A   ANNUAL  April   10021.34   0
1   Com A   MONTHLY April   35.86 .    0
2   Com B   MONTHLY April   11150.05   1,003.50
3   Com B   ANNUAL  July    661.65     0
4   Com B   ANNUAL  August  303.63     0
5   Com C   ANNUAL  April   25624.59   2,306.21
6   Com D   ANNUAL  June    27309.26   2,457.83  
7   Com D   ANNUAL  July    0.00       0
8   Com D   ANNUAL  August  0.00       0
9   Com E   ANNUAL  April   10.65      0
10  Com E   MONTHLY May     0.00       0
11  Com E   ANNUAL  May     18716.70   1,684.5
12  Com E   MONTHLY June    0.00       0
13  Com E   ANNUAL  June    606.49     0
14  Com E   MONTHLY July    0.00       0
15  Com E   MONTHLY July    8890.17    800.11
16  Com E   MONTHLY August  4000       0
17  Com E   ANNUAL  August  16000      1,800
18  Com E   ANNUAL  September 2157.34  0
19  Com E   ANNUAL  October 3025.24    0
```

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e705W.png)

Comment: When you group by `Deal` and `Month` the usual intent is to aggregate the remaining columns (e.g. by summing them, taking the last one, the maximum and so on). It's not clear what you intend for the `Type` column in this case. e.g. since you've grouped all the "Com A" deals in April together, what TYPE should this group have?

Comment: I was trying to express the sum of the rows for example, for Com A in "Deal" I want to add all the rows in Amount for Com A and check if the sum of those rows is >= 18000

Comment: Cool. So you can do that by e.g. `af = df.groupby(['Deal','Month'])['Amount'].sum()`. But now the total amount for e.g. Com A in April is a mix of monthly and annual types. Did you mean to apply the formula calculating the 9% *before* summing the amounts?

Comment: I want to keep the monthly and annual types in the "Type" column separate, even if they're in the same month, for Com A, i want the function to first add 10,021.34 + 35.86 to check if its >=20000 (sorry I meant 20000 not 18000)  and if it is then apply .09 to x and insert that value in the last row of the Desired Column for Com A, the second rule of the function would be to check if all the rows that have "MONTHLY" in "TYPE" column add up to >=1500 and if thats true then apply * .09 to x

Comment: So the "Desired Column" can either have 0, or 9% of the sum of all rows in a "Deal" depending on whether the sum is >=20,000 OR (>=1500 & TYPE =="MONTHLY")

Comment: Just wanted to provide another example, For Com B, Since the TYPE == "MONTHLY" & Amount is greater than 1500 it applies .09 * 11,150.05 to get 1,003.50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to translate your description into this:

```
df['Sum'] = df.groupby(['Deal','Month'])['Amount'].transform('sum')

df['Desired Column'] = np.where(df['Sum'] > 20000, df['Sum'] * 0.09, np.where((df['Amount'] >= 1500) & (df['TYPE'] == 'MONTHLY'), df['Amount'] * 0.09, 0))
```

Though I found some differences between the result I generated and the "Desired Column" you posted, e.g. in row 16, it's monthly and has amount greater than 1500, so the result should have been 0.09 * 4000 = 360, not sure how you got 0. I guess either you made a mistake during manual calculation or probably I misunderstood your description, please feel free to explain it 
so that I can update my script, but I guess the general idea should have solved your problem.

P.S. the result df after running my script

```
   Deal     TYPE      Month    Amount       Sum  Desired Column
0     A   ANNUAL      April  10021.34  10057.20          0.0000
1     A  MONTHLY      April     35.86  10057.20          0.0000
2     B  MONTHLY      April  11150.05  11150.05       1003.5045
3     B   ANNUAL       July    661.65    661.65          0.0000
4     B   ANNUAL     August    303.63    303.63          0.0000
5     C   ANNUAL      April  25624.59  25624.59       2306.2131
6     D   ANNUAL       June  27309.26  27309.26       2457.8334
7     D   ANNUAL       July      0.00      0.00          0.0000
8     D   ANNUAL     August      0.00      0.00          0.0000
9     E   ANNUAL      April     10.65     10.65          0.0000
10    E  MONTHLY        May      0.00  18716.70          0.0000
11    E   ANNUAL        May  18716.70  18716.70          0.0000
12    E  MONTHLY       June      0.00    606.49          0.0000
13    E   ANNUAL       June    606.49    606.49          0.0000
14    E  MONTHLY       July      0.00   8890.17          0.0000
15    E  MONTHLY       July   8890.17   8890.17        800.1153
16    E  MONTHLY     August   4000.00  18000.00        360.0000
17    E   ANNUAL     August  14000.00  18000.00          0.0000
18    E   ANNUAL  September   2157.34   2157.34          0.0000
19    E   ANNUAL    October   3025.24   3025.24          0.0000
```

Comment: sorry i meant for that to be 4,000 + 16,000 = 20,000, good catch

Comment: yes it does, thank you! I'll accept your answer but is there anyway to only apply the value in desired column in the last row of the month? So that there are no repeated values/duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `groupby` in this case. There are a couple of ways to do it, conceptually easiest is to first calculate the threshold based on whether it is a monthly amount or an annual one

```
df['Threshold'] = (df.TYPE=='ANNUAL')*20000 + (df.TYPE=='MONTHLY')*1500
```

Then you can calculate the amount based on whether the threshold has been met

```
df['Desired Amount'] = (df.Amount>df.Threshold)*0.09*df.Amount
```

But this works here because you don't have multiple rows for the same deal, month, and type. If you did then you would first need the groupby to aggregate by all of these

```
df = df.groupby(['Deal','Month','TYPE']).sum()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Then you can proceed as above.

Comment: each calculation for the desired column has to happen on a monthly basis, and should correspond to each specific deal, so it has to check for the specified criteria for each month, ANNUAL and MONTHLY types must remain separate so I know which type to attribute the Amount to, to reiterate, if the monthly total amount, (regardless of the TYPE) is equal to or more than 20,000 then 9% should be applied to the monthly total amount, if not then ONLY the MONTHLY types should be summed to see if they equal or greater than 1500 and if so then apply 9% if none of these then 0

Comment: Ah ok, i misunderstood. But I see it's been solved below.